# Python histogram plotting: - y axis not normalized for large array

Tags: python, statistics, histogram

hi all i have the following code for an assignment for class-
i was asked to plot an normalized histogram for M={1000,10000,1000000} vector of Random variables with an exponential distribution, and to see Central limit theorem for large enough vector.
for an array of 1000 (m=1000) i get a histgram were the y axis is <1
however when i go up to an array of 10000 and above i get a histogram were the y axis is >1, and the x axis shrunken in return.
this of course is still mathematically correct  but i would like to get the y axis to be between
 y=[0,1]

i have tried density=True, and tried via plt.hist but has not worked, also i have tried a weights solution with the size of the array, that was posted here, but non have worked. :([10000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDTfQ.png) [1000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wA0d.png)

and advise?

i have added a picture of the histogram for an array of M=1000, and M=10000

```
import random 
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import seaborn as sns
def questb(M):
Lambda=0.1
L=5
N=500
histgram=[]
Sum=0
w=0
temp=[]
for m in range(0,M):
    for i in range (0, N//L):
        for j in range (0,5):
            temp.append((-1/Lambda)*math.log(random.uniform(0.0,1.0)))
        w=(min(temp))
        Sum=Sum+(w-2)
        w=0
        temp=[]
    Sum=(L*1.0/M*1.0)*math.sqrt(N*1.0/L*1.0)*Sum
    histgram.append(Sum)
    Sum=0
return histgram
M=10000
thefinalhistgram=questb(M)
sns.set(color_codes=True)
sns.distplot(thefinalhistgram);
plt.title(M)
plt.show()
```

Comment: you simply just want to make the y values between 0 and 1?

Comment: yes, but of still be mathematically correct, if the x values will also be between 0,1 as it is in the M=10000 example, its no good

Comment: I would like that the y axis will show probability, therefor be between [0,1]

Comment: why don't you just scale them?

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: scale your x-values so the max is 1, and do the same for the y-axis?